Encountering an error when we attempt to set the 'Sites.Selected' permission from the application level using Graph API
Our application is multitalented and registered in the Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com). Let's say the name of the application is "Target Application." We have granted permission for the Graph API in the Azure Portal, and we are trying to fetch documents from a demo site. Here demo site also registered in azure portal but in a different domain. After that, we have assigned the permission Sites.Selected to the demo application, but we are unable to fetch the documents and are receiving an "access denied" error when attempting to use this Graph API:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sitesId}/permissions
Content-Type: application/json{ 
 "roles": ["write"],
 "grantedToIdentities": [{
    "application": {
      "id": //Target Application’s Client Id
      "displayName": //Target Application’s Display name
    }
  }]
}

are we missing any configuration at the application level?

Here is the token-generate SS:


Could you include how you are generating bearer token with what flow and API permissions?

generating a token using Postman, here is the details:
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Are you trying to access site from same tenant or different tenant? Could you add more details regarding that for clarity?

different tenant.

Are you generating token from one tenant and using it to access site in different tenant?

No, generate a token using the same tenant and access that site under that tenant.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The error usually occurs if the token does not have required permissions to perform the operation.
Initially, I too got same error when I tried to make POST request with token having only Sites.Selected permission:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sitesId}/permissions
Content-Type: application/json
{ 
 "roles": ["write"],
 "grantedToIdentities": [{
    "application": {
      "id": //Target Application’s Client Id
      "displayName": //Target Application’s Display name
    }
  }]
}

Response:

To resolve the error, make sure to add "Sites.FullControl.All" permission of Application type and grant consent to it as below:

Now, I generated the token again using client credentials flow via Postman like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Response:

To confirm that, you can decode this token in jwt.ms and check permissions in roles claim as below:

When I used this token to make POST request for creating permission, I got the response successfully like this:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sitesId}/permissions
Content-Type: application/json
{ 
 "roles": ["write"],
 "grantedToIdentities": [{
    "application": {
      "id": //Target Application’s Client Id
      "displayName": //Target Application’s Display name
    }
  }]
}

Response:

Reference:
Create permission - Microsoft Graph v1.0

This works for me; just we need to add the YYY app Sites.Selected permission, at both the SharePoint and Microsoft Graph levels as well.
